# Webcam with built-in background removal

Tags: windows, webcam

I am looking for a webcam that has a built-in background removal feature.

- Built-in = done in the webcam firmware+hardware, and not on the operating system of the device to which the webcam is attached.
- Background removal feature = only shows the human face/upper body that appears on the video
- Budget: up to around 300USD (no hard limit)
- Preferred country of purchase: United States
- Compatible operating system: Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate

Comment: This is a very complex machine vision task that requires a CPU, RAM, and some sort of *software*. If you find a camera to do this it probably has an ARM CPU and running Linux in it.

Comment: FYI I'm still interested in this question.

Comment: I can envision a "stand-alone" SBC such as the Pi, running a suitable camera (many from which to choose) and a form of software capable of the tasks required. I know only of OpenCV as an open source package, but not sure if it will do as needed. Of course, all of the above requires someone to create the program, but I suspect it's not going to be impossible.